# Using one workflow all over organisation in GitHub

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

As title says, I would like to use one workflow all over organisation. Is that even possible without required workflows, since they are deprecated now?

I tried to set ruleset that will trigger that workflow, but the problem is that I need that workflow to be triggered on each change and creation of any Pull Request, but for some reason it is triggered only on creation of Pull Request.
This is my workflow:

```
name: "[org-req-workflow] workflow1"
permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: write
  checks: write
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [assigned, unassigned, labeled, unlabeled, opened, edited, closed, reopened, synchronize, ready_for_review, locked, unlocked, review_requested, review_request_removed]
jobs:
  provision-runner:
    uses: provisioner location
    with:
      AWS_OIDC_ROLE: arn role

  check-what-is-needed:
    needs: provision-runner
    runs-on:
      #config
    steps:
      - name: do what to do
        run: |
          curl -X POST '${{ secrets.URL }}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '${{ toJSON(github.event) }}'
```

Comment: There is a rule "[require workflows to pass before merging](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/available-rules-for-rulesets#require-workflows-to-pass-before-merging)", but it is available only on GitHub Enterprise.

Comment: @BenjaminW.I'm using that rule, but a problem is that for some reason it is only running when PR is created. Actually, in repo where workflow is located, it is running as it should. But in other repos it is running only when PR is created. Once it is updated, it doesn't rerun that specific workflow

Comment: It should trigger on at least the default types, which are `opened`, `reopened`, and `synchronize`. We use such a workflow, and it has just an `on: pull_request` trigger, but runs on all synchronize events on a PR.

Comment: @BenjaminW. that's exactly why I posted :) It should be working fine, but for some reason it doesn't

Comment: @BenjaminW. can you give me an example how do you use it in other repo? Do you have ruleset for this? Or you use it as reusable workflow? Or something totally different?

Comment: I don't have a public example, but the workflow is a regular workflow, which is selected when configuring the required workflow rule.